# What is the best font to apply to a print stylesheet?

Tags: css, fonts

When developing a print stylesheet for a web page, what fonts are recommended for use?

I was using Times New Roman, but it looks kinda bland.

What have you used before? IIRC they say serif fonts are easier to read on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the purpose, length, and location of the text.

Serif fonts are definately easier to read in large blocks, however san-serif fonts are easier to read as headlines.

I am a fan of plain, standard fonts--nothing fancy.  So, for me, I like Times New Roman for large areas of text and Arial for headlines.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd have said. Make sure you specify alternate and generic typefaces to cover all situations.

Answer (score 2):

I myself am a big fan of [Gentium](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=gentium) for printing.

I use it for things other than printing too, its just so sexy.

[Gentium Sample http://www.imagepaste.com/img/f9234d922fead5b3590b465ee0249ff6.png](http://www.imagepaste.com/img/f9234d922fead5b3590b465ee0249ff6.png)

The only **really** obvious problem is, using a print style-sheet, you can't make any assumptions yet about what fonts the user has installed.

Times New Roman is becoming more ubiquitous, but its not available by default on many non-windows platforms.

There is progress being made in the realm of user-specified and download-on-the-fly font support, but its not very reliable yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Gentium.  I've downloaded it and will be trying it out soon.

Comment: Unless you control the target audience's machines (like on an intranet), I wouldn't even bother with any non-standard fonts.

Comment: The problem is there are no 'standard fonts', that's my whole point.

Answer (score 0):

Freedom is a major consideration for me when selecting a font to use for any purpose.  I have adopted the [Deja Vu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) family of fonts for my general purpose use, Deja Vu Sans in particular.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {
    body {
        font: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 11pt;
    }
}
```

Always good to use Serif fonts.

Comment: @alex, this is because the serif make the individual letters more distinctive and easier for our brains to recognize quickly. Without the serif, the brain has to spend longer identifying the letter because the shape is less distinctive.

Source - http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w017.html